# How to get data from java code into flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello guys am new to flutter and want to know about the native calls, I used method call and successfully got response from the java code(Native code). I can get the data only if i invoke method from the flutter right? Is there a way to get the data from the java code whenever the data is available?

For ex: We have an communication SDK which will post events to the java code, i want to use those events in my flutter, Hope you understand my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you mean a transpiler or something

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for methods on the Dart side too. MethodChannel has a callback called `setMethodCallHandler()` :

```
MethodChannel methodChannel = MethodChannel("channel name");
methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler((call) {
  if (call.method == "your method name") {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, i can do that, what if i want to listen continuously? Thats my problem

Comment: This listens continuously. The handler will be called every time you call `invokeMethod()` on the native side.